# Form submits even after validation function throws Uncaught Exception

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a form on whose validation function a line throws an uncaught exception, but instead of stopping the execution the browser submits the form

http://jsfiddle.net/yur4U/1/

```
 function validation(){
   var value = document.forms["myform"]['badInput'].value;//this line throws an exception
   return false;
 }​

<form name='myform' action ="" onsubmit="return validation()" method="POST">
    <input name='myInput' value="testing" type="text"/>
     <input value="submit" type="submit"/>
</form >
```

the code above provides one is a simple example , but i might be doing some calculations or conversions which might produce an Exception.
One way to handle this is to enclose it in try catch

```
function validation(){
   var ret =true;
   try{
       var value = document.forms["myform"]['badInput'].value;
       ......//some condition to make ret=false
   } catch(e){
       ret = false
   }
   return ret;
 }​
```

But I am searching for a better way to do this? I think browser should be handling this by default, is this mentioned anywhere in the spec about how a browser should behave if onsubmit function throws an Exception?

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = document.forms["myform"]['badInput'].value;
//this line throws an exception
```

Because there is no "badInput" named element in your form. Although it is better to use `form.elements["elementName"]` or even better use a JS framework (like jQuery / dojo / etc.).

If you still need this line, you could check with `typeof`:

```
if (typeof document.forms["myform"].elements['badInput'] != "undefined")
   ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i know it throws an error, i purposely wrote that, as i said it is a simpler example, but there might be some line of code which might throw some other exception, i want to know is there a default way to handle those or do i need to use try/catch?

Comment: Use try/catch if you want to handle all exceptions, or detect manually with `typeof`, i wrote above.

Comment: that i know, but shouldn't the browser handle it by default, ie it should not submit the form after it encounters an exception, it this a bug in the browsers or by functionality?

Comment: No, if the browser encounter an exception, that javascript "thread" stops, so the line `return false` does not run, so the event propagation, and default action cancellation isn't set, so the form submits.